# Connect to SSH on server, and then see output from existing console sessionn

Tags: linux, ssh

Once connected to an existing Linux server, is it possible to view the output of an existing console session running locally on the server (via KDE)?  I've seen mention of screen in my research but I'd like to see a session which is running now, without having to install new software...  is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest running screen, but the existing session would have to be started with screen.  I don't know of way to redirect an existing session to a new session any other way.

Install screen

start all session with `screen -D -RR`.   You can connect with a local or remote shell, and type the command and the screen will be detached from the previous shell (-D option) and reattached to the current shell (-RR option)

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought someone would say :( - Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the "console" you trying to access is a x11/KDE session(?)

to my knowledge, the quickest way would be to "record" the x11/KDE session for a few seconds via ffmpeg ( x11grab ), or create a single ( or more ) screen shots ( also via ffmpeg/x11grab ) in case you would like just to monitor/view the state of the session.

this can be done via ssh, without any remote control application.